# mysql : declare cursor after while loop

Tags: mysql

I have created one stored procedure. In that after performing some operation I want to declare cursor and get data from that cursor. But, it gives syntax error. Below is my stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `adserver`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getDaypartTimeDetail`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getDaypartTimeDetail`(currentDate DATE,noOfdays INT,cityId BIGINT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE TotalFiles, TotalDuration BIGINT;
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE da DATE;
    DECLARE dateCnt INT;


    SET dateCnt = 0;
    SET TotalFiles = 0;
    SET TotalDuration = 0;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_date;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_data;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_date(dday DATE); 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_data(dday DATE,daypartId INT,totalFile BIGINT,totalDur BIGINT); 

    WHILE(dateCnt < noOfdays) DO
        SET i = 1;
        INSERT INTO tmp_date(dday) VALUES (DATE_ADD(currentDate, INTERVAL dateCnt DAY));
    SET dateCnt = dateCnt + 1;
    END WHILE;

    DECLARE exit_flag INT DEFAULT 0; ****<-- Gives error**** 
    DECLARE dday DATE;
    DECLARE dId BIGINT;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET exit_flag = 1;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT dday, id FROM tmp_date, daypart;

    OPEN cur;
        all_details_id:LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO dday,dId;
            IF record_not_found THEN
                LEAVE all_details_id;
            END IF;
        INSERT INTO temp_data(dday,daypartId) VALUES (dday,dId);
        END LOOP all_details_id;
    CLOSE cur;

    SELECT * FROM temp_data;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @Madhivanan syntax error

Comment: Declare everything at the begining of BEGIN-END clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (quite strange) rule in MySQL which says that `DECLARE` statements should go right after `BEGIN` before any `SET`, `INSERT` etc statements. Please refer to this article http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/nesting-mysql-cursor-loops.html

So, your script should look something like the following:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `adserver`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getDaypartTimeDetail`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getDaypartTimeDetail`(currentDate DATE,noOfdays INT,cityId BIGINT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE TotalFiles, TotalDuration BIGINT;
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE da DATE;
    DECLARE dateCnt INT;

    DECLARE exit_flag INT DEFAULT 0; ****<-- Gives error**** 
    DECLARE dday DATE;
    DECLARE dId BIGINT;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT dday, id FROM tmp_date, daypart;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET exit_flag = 1;

    SET dateCnt = 0;
    SET TotalFiles = 0;
    SET TotalDuration = 0;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_date;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_data;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_date(dday DATE); 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_data(dday DATE,daypartId INT,totalFile BIGINT,totalDur BIGINT); 

    WHILE(dateCnt < noOfdays) DO
        SET i = 1;
        INSERT INTO tmp_date(dday) VALUES (DATE_ADD(currentDate, INTERVAL dateCnt DAY));
    SET dateCnt = dateCnt + 1;
    END WHILE;

    OPEN cur;
        all_details_id:LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO dday,dId;
            IF record_not_found THEN
                LEAVE all_details_id;
            END IF;
        INSERT INTO temp_data(dday,daypartId) VALUES (dday,dId);
        END LOOP all_details_id;
    CLOSE cur;

    SELECT * FROM temp_data;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this helps...